# Lie algebra using skew-symmetry

Tags: lie-algebras

Let g be a Lie algebra such that [[x,y],y]=0 for all $x,y \in g$. Show that 3[[x,y],z]=0 for all $x,y,z \in g$. [Hint: Observe that the mapping (x,y,z) to [[x,y],z] is skew-symmetric in x,y,z and make use of the jacobi identity.]

So I know that 
[[x,y],z]=[x,[y,z]]+[y,[z,x]] (using the jacobi identity)

So
3[[x,y],z]=3[x,[y,z]]+3[y,[z,x]], I need to use [[x,y],y]=0, but can't see how to do it. Like I would need to elimate x,y or z from 3[x,[y,z]]+3[y,[z,x]], but it just seems impossible.

Was wondering am I using skew symmetric wrong. I assume that skew symmetric is just this [x,y]=-[y,x].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skew symmetry in general means for a function $f$ of $n$ arguments that whenever $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ and $(y_1,\ldots, y_n)$ are permutations of each other, then $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\pm f(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$, where $\pm$ means $+$ or $-$ according whether the permutation is even or odd.

To prove that a function is skew symmetric, it is sufficient to show that
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_i,x_{i+1},x_{i+2},\ldots x_n) =
-f(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},x_i,x_{i+2},\ldots x_n) $$
for all $i$ -- that is, that interchanging any two neighbor arguments will flip the sign of the function result. If the function is known to be *linear* in each argument, it is also enough to prove that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$ whenever two of the $x_i$'s are equal.

Here this concept is being applied to the function $f(x,y,z)=[[x,y],z]$. The hint says to prove, based on $\forall xy: [[x,y],y]=0$, that this $f$ is skew symmetric. (You can do this without the Jacobi identity).

*Then*, write the Jacobi identity in the form $[[a,b],c]+[[b,c],a]+[[c,a],b]=0$, and use the just proved fact about $f$ to see that the left-hand side is equal to $3[[a,b],c]$.

Comment: I thought all Lie algebras are skew-symmetric. So in $[[a,b],c]+[[b,c],a]+[[c,a],b]=0$ do you just swap and change signs until you get it as $3[[a,b],c]$. I can see that. However, how would on go about proving f is skew-symmetric.

Comment: The Lie bracket _itself_ is skew-symmetric by definition, that is $[a,b]=-[b,a]$. But it does not follow from this that the three parameter function $(a,b,c)\mapsto [[a,b],c]$ is also skew-symmetric -- that requires not only $[[a,b],c]=-[[b,a],c]$ (which is true for all Lie algebras) but also, say, $[[a,b],c]=-[[a,c],b]$ (which isn't; consider e.g. $(\mathbf e_1 \times \mathbf e_2)\times \mathbf e_1$ in $\mathbb R^3$). The latter relation can be proved if you assume $[[x,y],y]=0$, however. (**Hint**: let $x=a$, $y=b+c$ and expand the LHS by linearity!)

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I did the expansion with x=a, y=b+c and can see where you use the fact [[x,y],y]=0. You been a lot of help so thank you.